# How to Programmatically Set Up Powershell Remoting on an Azure VM

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

My goal is to write a Powershell script that will run `New-AzureRmResourceGroup` and `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` in order to provision a resource group according to an ARM .json template file.  Said resource group includes a virtual machine, virtual network, network security group, public IP address, network interface attached to the virtual machine, and two storage accounts.  After that, I want the same script to go on and copy a specific program installer to the virtual machine in that resource group and run that installer, automatically without further user interaction.  However, I can't seem to begin a remote Powershell session with the virtual machine.  I run the command:

`$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName **.***.**.*** -Port XXXX -Credential $cred`

where the `*`s are the IP address of the Virtual Machine; `XXXX` is the Port that is open for RDP according to the Network Security Group associated with the virtual network that the Virtual Machine is on; and `$cred` contains the credentials of the admin user on the Virtual Machine.

The command always returns an error:

`New-PSSession : [**.***.**.***] Connecting to remote server **.***.**.*** failed with the following error message :
The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is
running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the
destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the
destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.`

Note that I did make sure to add the Virtual Machine's IP address to the list of Trusted-Hosts on my local machine.  (Until I did that, I got a different error message.)  Also, I **am** able to connect to the Virtual Machine if I click on its Connect button in the Azure portal and then click on the .rdp file that's downloaded.  This remote session uses the same IP address, port, and credentials as the one I'm trying and failing to set up in Powershell.  This is what I don't understand.

[image: The Connect button that produces a working .rdp]

Why does that happen?  Is there some additional work I need to do to prepare the VM for accepting remote Powershell sessions?  Is there any way to configure it in the ARM template so that the VM will be ready to accept them from the get-go? (It would be difficult if I need to run some commands on the VM to set Powershell remoting up, since I can't Powershell remote in to run them because of this very problem.  Maybe I could run them as a custom script extension?)

Final notes:  This VM is "new" style, not "classic" style.  I know there is lots of documentation out there for "classic" style Azure VMs, but that's not what I'm working with.  Also, even after running `winrm quickconfig` on the VM as the error suggested, and enabling administrative rights remotely to local users, I get the same error when I run `New-PSSession`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open up 5985-5986 on your NSG
2. Drop the port part on your command:

   $sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName **.**.**.** -Credential $cred

WinRM endpoint is set up automatically for new VM's (if you don't somehow override it). But you need to open 5985 for nonsecure and 5986 for secure remoting

Comment: I got a different error this time:
`New-PSSession : [40.123.50.2] Connecting to remote server 40.123.50.2 failed with the following error message : WinRM
cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over
the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer.`

I ended up having to go into Windows Firewall on the VM and enable "Windows Remote Management (Http-In)" for Public profiles anywhere, not just on the subnet.  Is there a way to do this in the ARM template?

Comment: Now this is weird, I don't remember having to do so even once. As for the arm part, I've never heard about that, and quick internet search doesn't reveal something like that, but it doesn't mean that its not possible. Althou likely not. By the way, winrm qc configures firewall (but not for public profile)